How do lattice based LWE protocols match their keys after generating them?
I am trying to implement a cryptographic protocol based on the following paper explaining the creation of the Swoosh lattice-based NIKE. They also provide a Rust and Jasmine implementation which I have used to base my implementation. I managed to get to a point where I have somewhat of a code generating the keys, the errors, and everything needed, but my keys never seem to match, so I wonder how should the keys be matched? Should they even match or they can be close enough despite needing a reconciliation function?
I can provide the code and results if needed.

Posted under a different account here including code. Please don't do that.

See my answer on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78856297/implementation-of-lattice-based-nike-cryptographic-protocol-swoosh-not-working/78858498#78858498
